# finding the difference between two values of a dictionary inside a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
d=[{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35)}, {'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 13, 32, 35)}, {'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 22, 32, 35)}]
```

I want to iterate the list and check whether the difference between two DateTime objects is equal to one hour using python.

**Our final list should be 
   new_list = [{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35)},{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 13, 32, 35)}, {'temp': None, 'date': None}{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 22, 32, 35)}]**

I am new to python. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: One what, day's, months, years, etc... and are you comparing to a known datetime obj or are you wanting to compare to the next object in the list?

Comment: What do you mean by `1`, `1` what?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter: Compare to the next object in the list (only the values of 'date' key alone)

Comment: But what do you mean by one? If they are different by one second then the difference would be `00:00:01` and a difference by one minute would be `00:01:00` the difference of a year would be `365 days, 0:00:00`. You need to be specific.

Comment: Difference should be by one hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
import datetime
d = [{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 13, 32, 35)}, {'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35)}, {'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35)}]

def compare(data, field):
    #the code
    if len(data) <= 1:
        return
    ret = []
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        try:
            if v[field] - data[i+1][field] > datetime.timedelta(hours = 1):
                ret.append(v)
                ret.append(data[i+1])
            else:
                ret.append({x:None for x in v})
                ret.append({x:None for x in v})
        except:
            pass
    return ret

#testing
differences = compare(d, 'date')
print differences
for i, v in enumerate(differences):
    print 'differences[%s] is the difference between d[%s] and d[%s], The difference is: %s'%(i, i, i+1, 'Greater than one' if v['date'] else 'Less than one')
```

Comment: No problem partner.

Comment: And also if the if condition satisfies, I want both the temp and date to be appended as key,value pairs.if not,'None' should be appended as value for temp and date for the corresponding index.

Comment: Please explain. Create a desired output for me.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: for d in my question i am getting the output as [{'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 13, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': None, 'temp': None}, {'date': None, 'temp': None}] instead it should be [{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 32, 35)},{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 13, 32, 35)}, {'temp': None, 'date': None}{'temp': 39.1, 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 22, 32, 35)}]